# Function call resets passed global structs' fields

Tags: c++, struct, arduino, strtok

With reference to the code below: After calling the function `CheckSMS` and passing the struct * `DB1`, the fields are updated according the the `strtok` call. This function reads and parses a text message, storing its contents into char* fields of the DB struct.

In the main loop, I have called `Serial.println(DB1.last_order)` before and after calling the `CheckSMS` function. If I have received a text, the order is printed appropriately in the main loop, however on the next call to CheckSMS, `DB1.last_order` is cleared, replaced with a \n or a NULL or something. I cannot figure out why `DB1.last_order` does not retain its value, and rather, it is overwritten with every call to CheckSMS. Thanks for any help.

Note - All text messages contain "CMT+", therefore writing to DB1 only happens when a text is received. Calling `CheckSMS` when no text is received should simply skip through.

```
  int CheckSMS(Robot *DB1) {

  int j = 0;
  char  response[100];
  char  *pch;
  unsigned long previous;

  memset(response, '\0', 100);

  while(Serial2.available()>0){
       response[j] = Serial2.read();
       j++;
       Serial.println("inc");
  }

  delay(100);
  if (strstr(response, "CMT:") != NULL){ 
      DB1->new_message = strtok(response, " ,");
      DB1->last_phone = strtok(NULL, " ,");
      pch = strtok(NULL, " ,");
      DB1->last_date = strtok(NULL, " ,");
      DB1->last_time = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");
      DB1->last_order = strtok(NULL," ,\n");
      new_message = 1;  

  }

  else{
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you actually read data, as soon as this function returns all the `char*` pointers you sucked out of those `strtok` calls and saved in `DB1` will be dangling (eg. no longer valid), as the buffer to which they reference (point into), `response[]`, no longer exists. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794) is *seriously* worth a read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strtok` function returns pointers to the string you're tokenizing, the local array `response` in your case.  When the function returns the `response` array goes out of scope and disappears, leaving your structure with pointers to a string that no longer exists, and giving you *undefined behavior*.

You have a couple of solutions:

- Allocate the string dynamically using `malloc`, but then you must save it in the structure so you can `free` it when you're done with the structure
- Make the `response` array `static`, but then the next call to the function will have the same array leading the old data to be updated
- Pass in a string to store the response and use that string, the string must have a lifetime at least as long as the structure and don't change contents. The string can of course be a member of the structure itself

Comment: Would it make sense to make my `struct` have char arrays rather than pointers? And copy into them from response?

Answer (score 0):

The answer Joachim gave is correct, I just want to add that you could also change the Robot structure to contain char arrays (like this: `char  new_message[MAX_BUF_CHARS];` and so on). Be sure to have enough space in them. Then instead of assigning the pointers returned from strtok, copy the strings in there.

Comment: oh.. yeah.. that was my question in the comment to Joachim. Thanks